# Binary search on a path of minimum heap

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, binary-trees, heaps, binary-search

WhereTo(H,X) is searching for the place to set X (an integer) in a minimum heap-H.
The function is executing a binary search on a path of a heap.

Assumption: We have the specific path because it starts on the last available leaf which is the last index in the array that doesn't contain any value, and there is only one path to the top from there.  Returns the specific index where we should put variable X. 
The main idea is to achieve time complexity of O(loglogN) to know exactly the index of the place to put X.

Implementation of the heap:
The element at index i has children at indices 2i
and 2i + 1 and parent at index floor((i) ∕ 2).

**The problem is, I don't really sure how should I define 'Mid' using 'Low' and 'High'.**

***EDIT: I think I found the formula:***

$Mid$ = $Floor(High/2^{Floor(Log(High/Low)/2)})$

Maybe it is an easy arithmetical problem.

Example(In the picture): While executing WhereTo(X), I want a binary search to start on the yellow path (next available slot from the leaf to the root and the mid to be 14 or 7 (at the beginning) and of course to be updated in every iteration

[image]

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What is the setup? What is the input of the function WhereTo? What is the expected output? It is a complete binary tree? How is the complete binary tree specified? It looks like you have become so familiar with the problem it did not occur to you that others are not.

Comment: "returns the specific index where we should put variable X" .X is an integer (It's minimum heap, of course it is a number) . The heap is represented by an array (there is one-to-one function between a heap represented by a binary tree to a heap represented by an array).

Comment: You can't know where to binary search without knowing the path to binary search. This path will take $\log(n)$ time to find. So your algorithm would end up begin $O(\log n)$ anyway. For instance, in your max heap example, the path would not be $\{16, 14, 7, nil\}$, but rather $\{16, 14, 8, 4\}$. You would not sift $7$ up before sifting $8$ up.

Comment: If I start from the leaf 'Open Slot' (lets assume I have pointer to there- O(1)) and I know there is only one path to the root. so I have to figure how I'll get the full path (indexes of path) to apply a binary search. Maybe this method is wrong but I know for sure I can achieve O(log log N) for this problem (maybe by useing more space?!)

Comment: @Yar.G Please edit the question to specify exactly how your heap is implemented. Is it [this common implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation) where "the element at index i has children at indices 2i + 1 and 2i + 2 and parent at index floor((i − 1) ∕ 2)"?

Comment: Edited, Although the implementation isn't important since I noticed that the data structure is a minimum heap  (=priority queue) and you can represent every heap as an array. I want to find the formula to get the middle index every iteration.

Comment: @Yar.G It may be a surprise to you, but your question is **far from well-defined**. If you discovered/created this problem by yourself, please write a detailed specification such as the ones in various programming contest. If you read the problem from somewhere, please provide an accessible reference or copy and paste the original description at it is.

Comment: @Yar.G Once there has been accurate description of the problem, that is, what is the input and how it is presented as a sequence of integers and what is the expected output as a sequence of integers, a satisfying answer will, I would bet, manifest shortly.

Comment: I want another person to tell me my question is "far from well-defined" so i'll be fully convinced. The problem is so simple: define a formula to "mid" pointer in a binary search on a path of a minimum heap. the implementation is not important since it's an algorithmic problem (not code or programming one), and under the assumption that any heap can represented as an array same as a binary tree.

Comment: @Yar.G, I would agree it's not defined very well, but I think I get what you're asking. Is this understanding correct? : "Your goal is to insert an element into the heap. However, you are trying to insert it in the bottom of the heap and sift up. Instead of sifting it up in a linear search, you know the path from leaf to root will be sorted. So you want to binary search this path to find where to insert it." Is this correct? This is easy enough to do, but the adjustment will still take $O(\log n)$ after you identify where to put it.

Comment: @ryan . yes you are right. I don't want to use insertion at all, I know it takes $O(logn)$, I need just the index to put X there. The goal is to find the place to insert X in $O(loglogn)$ time complexity.